# How to know if 2 processes have access to common filesystem

Tags: java, networking, filesystems, distributed, identification

How would you detect if two (in my case java) processes can access at least one filesystem in common? (maybe including network shared filesystems).

Assume they could be on two machines sharing a disk, on separate machines, or simply two processes on the same machine. I'd love to keep my processes with normal user permissions so let's assume I can't write a file in the root of all filesystems to keep track of this.

Maybe using in some way the temporary directories.

Comment: Do they need to tell each other that they can access the file system?

Comment: They need to identify the filesystem uniquely so they know if they can pass files trough filesystem or they must send files over network.

Comment: Can the processes talk to each other in some way already?

Comment: Yes, they communicate (in my case by means of JMS messaging)

Answer (score 1):

Don't. If they're on separate machines passing data through the filesystem will be a lot slower than a simple socket connection.  If they're on the same system the socket connection will not involve the network physical layer and will likely also be faster than using disk.

Using disk and having to manage two transports is just introducing complexity for no reason.

Comment: If the data is on the same filesystem I'm not going to replicate it, because only read access is needed I'd like process1 to say "hey, file is ready at /tmp/foo.bar" and process2 "ok, I'm gonna read it from the disk, if we share the same disk". (assume files are big 100 Gb or so)